# If a function runs in one thread and if it calls another function runs it in the smae thread?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

In my script are two "main" functions. Each of them is calling other functions. These two main functions are running in two dirffent treads. Are these functions also called in these thread or they running in the main thread?
Example:

```
def main(): 
 //something
 function1()
def main2():
 //something
 function2()
t1=threading.Thread(target=main)
t2=threading.Thread(target=main2)
t1.start()
t2.start()
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are these functions also called in these thread? - Yes.

Answer (score 0):

They will run on the thread on which they are called. For instance, the function `function1` will run on the same thread as `main`.